# About using of packages that your composer library suggests

Tags: php, composer-php

I am developing some composer php library.

And I want to provide library users to use class that uses some external package. I suggest this package in the relevant composer section.

Should I check that the composer's suggested package is really installed?

Will there be an error if the user just install my library without suggestions, but will not use this class that dependent from not installed package?

I checked some popular packages and seems to be they just use suggested packages as if they are already installed.

For example: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/c861fcba2ca29404dc9e617eedd9eff4616986b8/src/Monolog/Handler/ElasticsearchHandler.php

This monolog class just uses Elasticsearch classes as usual, but `Elasticsearch` is a suggested package and may be not installed.

Answer (score 1):

The handlers use the other packages as if they were installed - but keep in mind that Monolog does not use each and every handler automatically. If you define that such a handler (in your example: the one for ElasticSearch) is used, it is up to the user to know how to handle this.

As you can see in the constructor of that method, it is not even instantiable if you don't have a package for ElasticSearch installed - the code example in that class helps to understand this situation. So, no, this class is not usable without having another package installed, but the error will be thrown by your classloader. No need for the package to check for this